# What is the plural form of the word “coursework”?

Tags: plural-forms

I wonder what is the plural form of the word “coursework”?

Courseworks seem to be incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Coursework" is a mass noun, which means it is uncountable and used in similar ways to other mass nouns you might be more familiar with. Think *water*, *love*, or *ass-kicking*.

Here is a sentence from [Cambridge English Corpus](https://www.cambridge.org/gb/cambridgeenglish/better-learning/deeper-insights/linguistics-pedagogy/cambridge-english-corpus)

> Studio courses are intended as the point of integration for all other **coursework** and educational experiences. ([source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/coursework))

Similarly, words such as "schoolwork" and "homework" are also mass nouns. You can't count them or pluralize them.

> My science teacher always sets a lot of homework.

Comment: *Ass-kicking* is not a mass noun. "If you don't finish this soon I will give you an ass-kicking." *Water* is primarily a mass noun, and *love* is commonly a mass noun ('Love is the most important thing to have in your life.'), but is often a countable noun as well ('She is the love of my life.'; 'Find a new love.').

Comment: Thanks. Is there any website that I can use to find out if a noun is accountable or not?

Comment: @Brandin A lot of words are not strictly mass nouns. Of course, we could find words that are "more" uncountable than others, whose plural forms are considered non-idiomatic, as examples. I was just giving examples off the top of my head and wasn't trying to list "pure" mass nouns. "Ass-kicking" is also a mass noun. "I have some ass-kicking to do."

Comment: @LeiXun Try MacMillan and Cambridge Dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

Coursework (uncountable) can encompass a wide range of activities, including practice, experimentation, research, and writing. As for the latter, the term is a [coursework essay](http://writejoy.com/coursework-essays-structure.jsp), for example:

> There was a pile of coursework essays on the table.
>
> How many coursework essays have you read today?